# Is there anything special with a 3x3 matrix where the 3rd row is 0 0 1?

Tags: matrices

I'm coding using p5.js and I'm looking at this method https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/applyMatrix

Using that method, I can multiply my current matrix with any matrix of the form:

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    a & c & e \\
    b & d & f \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

by calling **applyMatrix(a, b, c, d, e, f)**

There is no method for multiplying any arbitrary matrix like:
$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    4 & 5 & 6 \\
    7 & 8 & 9 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

Is there anything special with a matrix of that form? Is it possible to convert any arbitrary matrix (like the bottom matrix) into a matrix of that form?

Comment: Do you have a question about math?

Comment: My question is about matrices not the coding itself, I just put the link there for context.

Comment: Your question appears to be about some programming language.

Comment: You could fit your $3 \times 3$ matrix into the larger matrix
$$
\pmatrix{1&2&3&0\\4&5&6&0\\7&8&9&0\\0&0&0&1}
$$
which I would say is a "matrix of that form"

Comment: My question is about whether there's something special about a matrix of a certain form, which is a purely math question. The context is that the programming language I use uses that form so I'm asking if there's anything mathematically special about it.

Comment: @DarkPotatoKing It is used to represent affine transformations. (This is also hinted at in the page you linked.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a standard way to represent an [affine transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Affine_transformations) of the plane; this is how it is used on the page you linked. The submatrix  $A = \begin{pmatrix} a & c \\ b & d \end{pmatrix}$ in your question represents the linear part of the affine transformation, and the extra column $t = \begin{pmatrix} e \\ f \end{pmatrix}$ to the right corresponds to the translation part of the transformation. In full, the corresponding transformation maps a vector $v$ to the vector $Av + t$.